What is this drum breakdown called?
The Show Goes On by Bruce Hornsby and the Range (Spotify, YouTube).
At about 45 seconds into the song, some familiar drums start playing. For lack of a better word, I called this a "drum breakdown" in the title since I am inexperienced with music in general.
For some reason I associate these drums with the end of 90s movies and TV, when the piano settles out and the drums start seeping in the corny message and emotion.
I have no idea what this technique (if it even is one) is called, and while I can't for the life of me think of any other songs with this technique right now, I'm sure I've heard it before.
Can anybody help me out, or at least, name some other famous songs with a similar musical feature? Is this even a common thing?
Forgive my amateur understanding of music.

What you're describing is an arrangement of a piece of music. The introduction is played by a single instrument, in this case a piano. Then there will be a point at which other instruments join in. This requires the band to be on the same page regarding the speed of the music (tempo), and the drums are responsible for setting that tempo. This is why you hear the drums as the primary instrument for four bars, then the whole band comes in, playing the same musical theme as the solo piano.
My suggestion to better understand this is to play the music from the beginning and tap your foot to the music. What you will discover is that the solo piano is not playing a fixed rhythm. If this was classical music the notation would be ad lib (freely). Then the point comes where the whole band plays, and the music switches to a steady beat (a tempo). The drums are the instrument that manages this transition for the band.
This is the same principle as a band leader shouting "One! Two! One, two, three, four..." as a count-in for the band. It sets both the speed and starting point for the band. And of course there are many other ways this can be handled.
As far as other examples of this arrangement, try The way it is (also by Hornsby).

As far as I understand, what your saying is that there really isn't a name for this specific kind of thing. And that this "drum breakdown" is just a quirk of how bands manage transitions. This makes sense, and the other example you listed is totally the feeling I was describing. As I was listening to it though, it sounded super familiar and weird. Turns out, "The Way it Is" was sampled by Tupac in "Changes" in the late 90s. Maybe that's why I described both these 80s songs as 90s feeling - I was ascribing them with a later movement.

By "drum breakdown" I think you meant "drumming style".
Bruce Hornsby's The Show Goes On uses a drumming style (see a drummer's reproduction) that this article labels as "neo soul." The linked article has a list of songs with a similar beat as well as the drum notation of a representative pattern. One of the songs listed is Erykah Badu's On & On whose drumming style sounds similar enough.
Disclaimer: I'm not a drummer. Others who know more of this music period and the names of the grooves, drumming styles, or rhythm names should be more authoritative.

While the song you linked might be the same genre, it's not specifically what I'm referring to. More than the style itself, I'm referring to the specific part of the song where the piano fades out and the drums come in. That familiar combination of instruments feels reminiscent of a cliche I've heard before.

@rabbibillclinton So it appears that I completely misunderstood what you meant, then.  The music starts with piano solo playing a repeated pattern of 4 or 3 notes emmeshed with 2 changing chords in the middle until around 0:30 where continuous backing strings joins and the piano became more active.  Piano slows down starting 0:45 (see rit. measure in this score) ending with an 8-beat-long Gadd2 chord that dies naturally, leaving just the strings for 3 seconds.

4 beats into that 8-beat-long chord, at 0:50, the drums comes in playing steady rhythm for a whole measure.  Then as you can see in the score, the piano comes back playing a bridge preparing for the next section (last measure of page 1).  So you're simply referring to the 4 beat fading away piano chord followed by the start of drum rhythm on its own?

Honestly, I have no exact idea what a chord, measure, or bridge is, but I'm pretty sure yes - that is what I am referring to. It's hard for me (a laymen with middle school band experience) to describe it, but the feeling is what I'm really what I'm getting at. Hardly objective, I know, but the best I can do right now.
